# MonadParallel Instance for Rand

Tags: haskell, random, parallel-processing

I'm currently working with computations in `ReaderT r (Rand StdGen) a` which I would like to run in parallel. I've come across [Monad Parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-parallel) which seems like it will do what I want.

There is already an instance of MonadParallel for `ReaderT` but I had to create my own for `Rand` from [monad-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom). However, I'm not sure I've done it right. I'm not too familiar with parallel programming in Haskell, but I believe that there is an expectation that running compuations in parrallel should give the same value as when they're run normally. Because my instance of bindM2 for Rand uses `split` (and therefore gets a different set of random numbers from the same initial generator) this isn't the case for my instance.

```
instance P.MonadParallel (Rand StdGen) where
    bindM2 f ma mb = do
        split1 <- getSplit
        split2 <- getSplit
        let a = evalRand ma split1
        let b = evalRand mb split2
        a `par` b `pseq` f a b
```

While I feel that there is a case for ignoring this (the numbers are still random, right?) I also can't help feeling that I'm missing something. Is this okay or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

My main concern is that this violates the guarantee that:

> Apart from the possible ordering of side effects, this function is equivalent to `\f ma mb-> do {a <- ma; b <- mb; f a b}`

These will have different results:

```
let g = mkStdGen 0
    r = evalRand (do x <- getRandom
                     y <- getRandom
                     return (x, y)) g
```

vs

```
let g = mkStdGen 0
    r = evalRand (P.bindM2 (\x y -> return (x,y)) getRandom getRandom) g
```

This does raise interesting questions about `split`, pseudorandom numbers, and the nature of random numbers in regards to purity. It's hard for me to imagine a case where your instance would have adverse affects, but the complexity of software systems has never stopped surprising me. And because of that, I wouldn't violate an expectation about `bindM2`, even if it is with random numbers.

Comment: It is an interesting question - probably not solvable without re-thinking how split works. As you said, in my case it's not exactly a concern but it's certainly work keeping an eye on.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inherent problem in `MonadParallel`'s `bindM2`. Its documentation says:

> Perform two monadic computations in parallel; when they are both finished, pass the results to the function. *Apart from the possible ordering of side effects,* this function is equivalent to `\f ma mb-> do {a <- ma; b <- mb; f a b}`

The problem is that in monadic computations (unlike applicative functors) **values can depend on effects**, and on their ordering too. So this requirement doesn't make much sense. Consider

```
do
  a <- getCurrentTime -- from Date.Time
  b <- getCurrentTime
  return (a <= b)
```

This returns always `True`, but if you reorder the effects, it'll start returning `False`.
Obviously by parallelizing the two computations, you'd get a very non-deterministic result.

So it's difficult to interpret the intention of `bindM2`. I'd say we could divide instances of `MonadParallel` into two categories:

1. Those that are really deterministic and for which `bindM2` is always equal to `\f ma mb-> do {a <- ma; b <- mb; f a b}`. That is, the order of effects doesn't change. Those implementations are usually defined using `par`, which doesn't change semantics of the program, only runs some parts in parallel.
2. Those that do depend on effect ordering, an thus `bindM2` can be arbitrarily different from `\f ma mb-> do {a <- ma; b <- mb; f a b}`. It seems that currently the only such instance is `IO`, which uses `forkIO` to spawn a new thread for one of the computations.

So whether you accept your `bindM2` as a valid instance or not depends on how you how you interpret the documentation. If you consider (2.) as invalid then your implementation is also invalid (and you should reject `IO` too). If you interpret (2.) as valid, then you don't have to be concerned.

Comment: The main issue here is really in using `split` for defining my instance for Rand. It's still deterministic (as far as I can tell) _but_ it produces a different result compared to the sequential version because of how `split` works.

However, considering the default instance for IO, would you consider usage of MonadParallel generally unsafe?

Comment: @TomSavage I understand. Safe or unsafe depends on what expectations you (or people who use your code) have. I don't think `MonadRandom` is unsafe in general, it's just that id isn't clear what `bindM2` should obey. It starts to be unsafe when someone expects something that isn't true. Perhaps the safest approach would be to create your own monad (or perhaps even monad transformer) suited specially for parallel randomized computations and document its exact behavior. IMHO this would be a nice and useful library. (You could use `MonadRandom` internally of course to implement it.)

Comment: @TomSavage If you use `IO`'s instance of `MonadRandom`, calling `bindM2` will have generally different results than calling the actions sequentially. So `Rand StdGen`'s instance is basically as correct as `IO`'s.